# Summing Values in Dictionary Based on Certain Values

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, conditional-statements

I have a list of dictionaries that state a date as well as a price. It looks like this:

```
dict = [{'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 50}, {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 12}, {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

I'd like to create a new list of dictionaries that sum all the Price values that are on the same date. So the output would look like this:

```
output_dict = [{'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 62}, {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried implementing anything? What happened?

Comment: The solutions using defaultdict did exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module:

```
from collections import Counter 

c = Counter() 

for v in dict:
    c[v['Date']] += v['Price']

output_dict = [{'Date': name, 'Price': count} for name, count in c.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 62},
 {'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

**OR, a new way:**

You can use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to solve this:

Install pandas like:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then code would be:

```
import pandas as pd

output_dict = pd.DataFrame(dict).groupby('Date').agg(sum).to_dict()['Price']
```

Output:

```
{Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'): 62, Timestamp('2020-06-02 00:00:00'): 60}
```

Comment: The pandas solution worked like a charm, thank you!

(for any newbies reading this, I replaced "dict" inside the brackets with the name of my initial dictionary)

Comment: I understand, and I appreciate your help, but I can only accept one answer and the solution that worked for me was the defaultdict one.

Comment: Sure. Did you try my solution with Counter? What was wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby

dct = [{'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 50}, {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 12}, {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]

out = []
for k, g in groupby(dct, lambda k: k['Date']):
    out.append({'Date': k, 'Price': sum(v['Price'] for v in g)})

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 62}, {'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools' [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), although I'd like to believe that [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will be faster :

```
#sort dicts
dicts = sorted(dicts, key= itemgetter("Date"))

#get the sum via itertools' groupby
result = [{"Date" : key,
           "Price" :  sum(entry['Price'] for entry in value)}
          for key,value in 
          groupby(dicts, key = itemgetter("Date"))]

print(result)

[{'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 62},
 {'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `defaultdict`

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

dct = [{'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 50},
       {'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 12},
       {'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]

sum_up = defaultdict(int)
for v in dct:
    sum_up[v['Date']] += v['Price']

print([{"Date": k, "Price": v} for k, v in sum_up.items()])
```

---

```
[{'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 62}, {'Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This a good use-case for defaultdict, let's say our dict is `my_dict`:

```py
import datetime

my_dict = [{'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 50},
           {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'Price': 12},
           {'Date':datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'Price': 60}]
```

We can accumulate prices using a defaultdict like so:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(int)

for dict_ in my_dict:
    new_dict[dict_['Date']] += dict_['Price']
```

Then we just reconvert this dict into a list of dicts!:

```py
my_dict = [{'Date': date, 'Price': price} for date, price in new_dict.items()]
```